# Move OS to new USB stick in Berryboot

Tags: raspbian, openelec

I am running Berryboot v2.0 with Raspbian and OpenELEC v4.0.6 installed. Initially I selected a usb stick (USB-A) as the destination drive. I want to install more OS's but USB-A is too small (4GB) so I want to move both Raspbian and OpenELEC to a new usb stick (USB-B, 16GB).

I tried copying the contents of USB-A to USB-B (formatted as Ext-4) but this did not work. I also tried cloning both OS's to USB-A and then moving the cloned image to USB-B but this didn't work.

What do I need to do to move my OS's to a new usb stick?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi but more about Operating systems and boot architecture in general. I think you will find more attention at Ubuntu Stack. Please accept an answer or post your solution and accept it if you can.

Answer (score 2):

1) Make image for your 4GB USB using dd (assuming your 4GB usb is sdb, count may vary according to usb size)

```
dd if=/dev/sbd of=4gb.img bs=1M count=4000
```

2) write the image to 16GB (assuming your 16GB usb is sdc, count may vary according to image size)

```
dd if=4gb.img of=/dev/sdc bs=1M count=4000
```

3) plug your 16GB usb to a desktop linux machine and bring up the gparted

4) select your usb & resize your rootfs partition to your need

5) if you want, run fsck.vfat to check for disk error

6) plugin the usb to rpi and enjoy :)